# How to check if Checkboxes and ranges are checked/set to max?

Tags: javascript

[**here you can see what I want to implement**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpLH0.png)

Hey I'm stuck at this: I want that the launch button gets enabled after all checkboxes are checked and all ranges are set to max.
But something like this won't work:

```
while(checkboxes.unchecked && ranges.value !== '100') {
    if (checkboxes.checked && ranges.value == '100') 
        document.getElementById('launch').disabled = false;
}
```

Any tipps for implementation?

Comment: could you please add jsfiddle? where is the checkboxes coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below uses the [HTMLFormElement interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) to reference `<form>`, `<input>`, and `<button>` (`<fieldset>` and `<legend>` as well if it was needed), you should notice it's terse syntax compared to the standard HTMLElement interfaces.

**Solution**

Wrap everthing in a `<form>` tag if you haven't already. Also assign a `[name]` shared between all ranges and a different `[name]` shared between all checkboxes. Reference it, then bind the event handler (ie `allFields(e)`) to the `<form>` and listen for the `"change"` event.

```
const form = document.forms[0];

form.onchange = allFields;
```

By default all event handlers pass the Event Object (`e`, `event`, `evt`, etc). Reference the `<form>` with `this` keyword coupled with the `.elements` property. That will result in a HTMLCollection of all `<input>`, `<button>`, `<fieldset>`, and `<legend>` within `<form>`.

```
function allFields(e) {
  const io = this.elements;
  ...
```

Next, reference all form controls assigned `[name="chx"]` (all checkboxes) and collect them into a HTMLCollection then convert it into a real array. Do so for all `[name="rang"]` (all ranges) as well.

```
  const chx = [...io.chx];
  const rng = [...io.rng];
```

Then run each array through the Array method `.every()` which will return `true` if all elements in the array are true for a given conditional. The condition for the ranges is `.value === '100'` and for the checkboxes is `.checked === true`.

```
  let allChecked = chx.every(c => c.checked === true);
  let allMaxRange = rng.every(r => r.value === '100');
```

Finally compare `allChecked` and `allMaxRange`.

```
  if (allChecked === true && allMaxRange === true) {
    io.launch.disabled = false;
  } else {
    io.launch.disabled = true;
  }
```

```js
const form = document.forms[0];

form.onchange = allFields;

function allFields(e) {
  const io = this.elements;
  const chx = [...io.chx];
  const rng = [...io.rng];
  let allChecked = chx.every(c => c.checked === true);
  let allMaxRange = rng.every(r => r.value === '100');
  if (allChecked === true && allMaxRange === true) {
    io.launch.disabled = false;
  } else {
    io.launch.disabled = true;
  }
};
```

```css
input,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.15;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

fieldset {
  height: max-content;
}

[type="range"] {
  width: 80%;
}

[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      <button id='launch' type='button' disabled>Launch</button>
    </legend>
    <input name='chx' type='checkbox'>
    <input name='rng' type='range' value='100'><br>
    <input name='chx' type='checkbox' checked>
    <input name='rng' type='range' value='100'><br>
    <input name='chx' type='checkbox' checked>
    <input name='rng' type='range' value='100'><br>
    <input name='chx' type='checkbox' checked>
    <input name='rng' type='range' value='100'><br>
    <input name='chx' type='checkbox' checked>
    <input name='rng' type='range' value='100'><br>
    <input name='chx' type='checkbox' checked>
    <input name='rng' type='range' value='100'><br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach :

You need to iterate over all checkbox elements as well as range elements.

Then use a flag variable to verify if all checkboxes/ranges are checked/max.

Use onchange/oninput event handlers. -> while loop is not necessary